# Python script executing two other python scripts asynchronously

Tags: python, subprocess, launch

I have a python script myscript that when run it "stays open" with a GUI. I would like to write a python script launching myscript two times like this:

```
bash>python runNTimes.py 2
```

I have the following code for runNTimes.py

```
import subprocess
for i in range(int(sys.argv[1])):
    subprocess.call(['python', 'myscript.py'])
```

The problem is that this happens synchronously, i.e. once I launch the first in a subprocess **the second subprocess is not launched until the first terminates**.

A minimal example for myscript.py:

```
try: 
        import Tkinter as tk # for Python2
except: 
        import tkinter as tk # for Python3

win=tk.Tk()
win.mainloop()
```

Comment: Call blocks, use Popen

Comment: @PadraicCunningham You beat my ninja edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Popen instead: `call()` blocks `Popen()` doesn't

```
from subprocess import Popen
import sys
for i in range(int(sys.argv[1])):
    Popen(['python', 'synccall1.py'])
```

synccall1.py

```
try: 
        import Tkinter as tk # for Python2
except: 
        import tkinter as tk # for Python3

win=tk.Tk()
win.mainloop()
```